# Why moving the code from html into .js causes issue?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, knockout.js, html-helper

I have asp.net mvc project with knockout.js so my index page is getting really huge because of lots of javascript functionality.
I'd love to move js code into a separate file but it does not allow me to apply it to the most of the code because if I have something like

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@Html.Raw(@Url.Action("Load"))",
```

Then it pops up a error if I move this part of the code into another file.
Please advise how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Javascript files are not parsed by ASP.net, so the variables you have of @Html.Raw and @Url.Action("Load") will never be processed.

Answer (score 0):

As @James Lai noted, **server side** code isn't parsed as such by ASP.Net. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6363981/304683) for a workaround, or you can pick and choose which scripts can still stay on the page (with server-side code) instead of the "everything" - your choice as to which approach meets your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript files are not parsed by ASP.NET MVC, thus `@Html.Raw(@Url.Action("Load"))` will not work in javascript file.

*Heres workaround*

Instead declare a variable in `view.cshtml`. In script section as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var actionUrl = '@Url.Action("Load", "Controller")';
</script>
```

And use `actionUrl` in javascript file.