# JavaScript functionality broken, once moved from in-line script to a separate file

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a working asp.net page, everything was working properly till I moved the Script content to a separate js file.
Example I have a script function:

```
function selectValue(){
var oldvalue = document.getElectByID(“<%=ddlAccountType.ClientID%>”).value
..
..
..}
```

Visual Studio is throwing an error saying JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property ‘value’ of undefined or null reference. And this is just one example. Please help!

Comment: you should refer to the `.js` in your `html`

Comment: I did the already <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="path"> </script>

Comment: asp.net syntax or content injection will not be available in .js files

Comment: @fmgp is there an alternative?

Comment: You'll have to pass the id in to your select function.

Comment: An alternative: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6363948/using-asp-net-tags-in-a-js-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because JavaScript files are read by the browser, never by the ASP.NET engine, even though they're resident on the server.  The ASP.NET engine therefore never processes your `(“<%=ddlAccountType.ClientID%>”)` tags.

Anything you want processed by the ASP.NET engine MUST appear on your page or in a user control.  You can try parameterizing your external-file methods and passing in the values, in this fashion:

```
function selectValue(id){
  var oldvalue = document.getElectByID(id).value;
  ..
  ..
..}
```

In your page:

```
selectValue("<%=ddlAccountType.ClientID%>")
```

By the way, you aren't really using "curly quotes" for your markup, are you?  That will probably cause you problems.

Comment: yes, i am using double quotes is it something like big "no no" for JS?

Comment: so this will also cause problem when i am trying to set a value of a server side control!

Comment: No, double quotes like this `"` are fine.  It's just curly double quotes (like you get when you paste from Word) that might be a problem.  They look like this:  `“”`

Comment: A server side control (like a user control) shouldn't be a problem.  The `.ascx` file is read and processed by the ASP.NET engine.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you moved the script out of your .aspx-file or whatever you used.

ASP.Net only compiles .aspx, .cshtml, .vbhtml, etc. -files, which means that your server-side code isnt compiled and will be parsed by the browser as javascript.

This will be parsed by the browser:

```
document.getElectById("<%=ddlAccountType.ClientID%>") // returns undefined

var oldvalue = undefined.value // JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property ‘value’ of undefined or null reference
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that your JS file doesn't recognize this tag

```
<%=ddlAccountType.ClientID%>
```

it only works on the .aspx file, but there is a solution/workaround:

in your .aspx use this snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var ddlAccountType = document.getElectByID(“<%=ddlAccountType.ClientID%>”);
</script>
```

and in your JS file:

```
function selectValue(){
var oldvalue = ddlAccountType.value
..
..
..}
```